Entity with UUID relationship error: a foreign key constraint fails. java spring
I'm trying save TaskCard entity
TaskCard Service:
public TaskCard create(TaskCardCreateData taskCardCreateData) {
    var creator = authenticatedUserService.getAuthenticatedUser();
    var taskCard = new TaskCard(
            taskCardCreateData.title(),
            taskCardCreateData.description(),
            taskCardCreateData.dueDate(),
            creator,
            taskCardCreateData.priority()
    );
    return taskCardRepository.save(taskCard);
}

Controller:
@PostMapping @Transactional public ResponseEntity createTaskCard(@RequestBody @Valid TaskCardCreateData taskCardCreateData, UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder){

    var taskCard = taskCardService.create(taskCardCreateData);
    var uri = uriComponentsBuilder.path("/taskcard/{id}").buildAndExpand(taskCard.getId()).toUri();

    return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(new TaskCardDetailData(taskCard));
}


Authenticated get user service:
public User getAuthenticatedUser() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    return (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
}

Entity User:
@Table(name="users")
@Entity(name="User")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;

    private String login;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "creator")
    private Set<TaskCard> taskCards;
...
}

Entity TaskCard:
@Table(name = "taskcards") @Entity(name = "TaskCard") public class TaskCard {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String title;
private String description;
private LocalDateTime createdDate;
private LocalDateTime updatedDate;
private LocalDateTime dueDate;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "creator_id")
private User creator;

public TaskCard() {
}

public TaskCard(String title, String description, LocalDateTime dueDate, User creator, String priority) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.createdDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
    this.creator = creator;
    this.priority = priority;
    this.status = TaskCardStatus.BACKLOG;
    this.active = true;
}...`

Error:
Hibernate: insert into taskcards (active, created_date, creator_id, description, due_date, priority, status, title, updated_date) values         (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
2024-08-27T22:44:36.744-04:00  WARN 35454 --- \[todolu\] \[nio-8080-exec-1\] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000 2024-08-27T22:44:36.744-04:00 ERROR 35454 --- \[todolu\] \[nio-8080-exec-1\] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (todolu.taskcards, CONSTRAINT fk_taskcards_users FOREIGN KEY (creator_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE) 2024-08-27T22:44:36.756-04:00 ERROR 35454 --- \[todolu\] \[nio-8080-exec-1\] o.a.c.c.C.\[.\[.\[/\].\[dispatcherServlet\]    : Servlet.service() for servlet \[dispatcherServlet\] in context with path \[\] threw exception \[Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement \[Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (todolu.taskcards, CONSTRAINT fk_taskcards_users FOREIGN KEY (creator_id) REFERENCES users (id\`) ON DELETE CASCADE)\] \[insert into taskcards (active,created_date,creator_id,description,due_date,priority,status,title,updated_date) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)\]; SQL \[insert into taskcards (active,created_date,creator_id,description,due_date,priority,status,title,updated_date) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)\]; constraint \[null\]\] with root cause

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (todolu.taskcards, CONSTRAINT fk_taskcards_users FOREIGN KEY (creator_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118) \~\[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0\]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) \~\[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0\]

everything happens normally in the database, success when inserting taskcards with valid UUID users and error when inserting invalid taskcards
I have already tried to instantiate and set the taskcard object in a traditional way without using the custom constructor created
Printing var's
example in service of this printing:
public TaskCard create(TaskCardCreateData taskCardCreateData) {    
var creator = authenticatedUserService.getAuthenticatedUser();
    System.out.println("CREATOR");
    var teste = creator.toString();
    System.out.println(teste);
    var taskCard = new TaskCard(
            taskCardCreateData.title(),
            taskCardCreateData.description(),
            taskCardCreateData.dueDate(),
            creator,
            taskCardCreateData.priority()
    );
    System.out.println("TASKCARD CREATOR");
    var testedois = taskCard.getCreator().toString();
    System.out.println(testedois);
    return taskCardRepository.save(taskCard);
}

CREATOR User{id=66386333-6465-3364-2d31-6665612d3464, login='luiz.jolo', password='$2a$12$FohqZ/qawqsrlhmFH0zoE.SoviWTjKN18Qyi6EnBcfZjm5qLbBn9y'} TASKCARD CREATOR User{id=66386333-6465-3364-2d31-6665612d3464, login='luiz.jolo', password='$2a$12$FohqZ/qawqsrlhmFH0zoE.SoviWTjKN18Qyi6EnBcfZjm5qLbBn9y'}
The same object!

What do authenticatedUserService.getAuthenticatedUser() returns?

@talex  Author has mentioned in the description as he tries to print the creator object, response => User{id=66386333-6465-3364-2d31-6665612d3464, login='luiz.jolo', password='$2a$12$FohqZ/qawqsrlhmFH0zoE.SoviWTjKN18Qyi6EnBcfZjm5qLbBn9y'}

Is that object received from DB or constructed in some other way?

Can you expand on this: "success when inserting taskcards with valid UUID users and error when inserting invalid taskcards"?

@talex Based on the code mentioned in the description, it retrieves the user details from the already-loaded Authentication object stored in memory and not from DB.

@SamPaulIsaac Looks like I need new pair of glasses :) but it explains problem. We need to see who set principal in Authentication object. Looks like it comes not from db.

@talex  'We need to see who set principal in Authentication object." - I agree.

Also, we need to VERIFY that the users table contains the user with the id that matches the creator_id being inserted into the taskcards table.

I concur that it's most likely the user was not persisted in the database before trying to persist the task card so the constraint can't be satisfied. You could try cascading the persist but unless you're making sure that each user has a unique id you'd risk ending up with multiple entities for the same user. Hence it's best to make sure the user is stored in the DB and to retrieve the proper id when loading the principal.

The success and error case mentioned refers to adding "taskcards" directly with SQL code to the database. If I try to add a "taskcard" with a non-existent or invalid UUID, the bank does not allow it.
In the database there is the user with the UUID mentioned in the code, as he authenticates normally and receives a JWT key and so I can capture this in "getAuthenticatedUser"

Problem solved!
Its my fail in the moment of create the database tables with flyway migrations, it's the type of id, i haved used VARCHAR(36) and i change now to BINARY(16) the user table and taskcards and the problem are solved. I should have postes the schema.
